# How can I deploy and run a python web server in an azure app service via docker

Tags: python, docker, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to get a python web server running in an Azure App Service. The container is created via the Dockerfile and pushed to an Azure Docker Registry. Continuous deployment is configured for the existing Azure App Service so that the changes are applied directly.  This step works correctly. In addition to the web server, I have set up SSH to connect to the container via the Azure Portal. This also gives me access to the container within the Azure App Service.

However, if I try to get a response from the web server running in the container from outside (e.g. `index.html`), all requests fail. Inside the container, however, the web server is running and responds correctly (`curl localhost:8080`)

Apparently the port used (8080) is not forwarded to the container, as the web server runs in the container and can also be reached from the outside when running locally.

**How do I get the python web server to run in the Azure App Service so that it can be accessed from outside?**

### What works

- Creating a Docker container with a python web application
- Pushing the Container to a Azure Docker Registry
- Continuous deployment to the Azure App Service
- SSH connection to the container via Azure Portal
- Start and run the web server in the container
- Accessing the index.html file served by the web server via `curl` within the container
- Starting the container locally and access `index.html` via browser

### What does not work

- Access to the index.html file provided by the web server from outside the container, i.e. from the internet

### What i have tried

- Changing the Port number within the Container to 8080, 80, 8008, 8000 or 443 in several configurations (web server port, EXPOSE port, WEBSITES_PORT setting)
- starting the web server without the sshd service
- enabling and disabling HTTPS
- changing the "HTTPS Only", "Always on", "HTTP 2.0 Proxy" and "HTTP version" settings of the Azure App Service
- Adding Application setting PORT with the value 8080
- Adding Application setting WEBSITES_PORT with the value 8080
- restarting, recreating and redeploying the Azure App Service
- examining the Log stream within the Azure Portal
- examining the Deployment Center logs within the Azure Portal

### Resources and suggested solutions that I came across during my research

- [Microsoft Documentation about custom containers for Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?tabs=debian&pivots=container-linux)
- [A developer who may have the same problem but no solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/168746/container-didnt-respond-to-http-pings-on-port-8080)
- [StackOverflow question about Port binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67755217/how-does-azure-app-service-manage-port-binding-with-docker-container-does-it-re)
- [An explanation of the differences of the PORT and WEBSITES_PORTS settings](https://azureossd.github.io/2023/02/15/Whats-the-difference-between-PORT-and-WEBSITES_PORT/)

### Observations

The container startup process fails because it does not respond to HTTP pings.

```
ERROR - Container <name> for site <name> did not start within expected time limit. Elapsed time = 230.2830234 sec
ERROR - Container <name> didnt respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
INFO - Stopping site <name> because it failed during startup.
```

Within the container all services are working

Azure uses this command to start the Container within the Web Service

```
docker run -d --expose=8080 --name <name> -e WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=false
-e WEBSITES_PORT=8080 -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=<app-service-name> -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False
-e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=<hostname> -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=<id>
-e WEBSITE_USE_DIAGNOSTIC_SERVER=False <DockerRegistry:Tag>
```

using this command locally to run the Container leads to the same result (index.html not reachable). It will however work if i add `-p 8080:8080` to the command.

### [The files i used](https://github.com/mtomberger/azuredockerpython)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have reproduced the same in my environment by [cloning your code](https://github.com/mtomberger/azuredockerpython).

**Local Response:**

[image]

- Initially I was also facing trouble to run the application after deploying to **Azure App Service** and was getting **"Application Error"**.

[image]

**Note:** After successful deployment of the application to Azure App Service, **you have to run the Startup Command to access and run the deployed application without any issues.**

- Navigate to your web app in `Azure App Service=> Settings=>Configuration=> General Settings` and enter the **Startup Command** **`python3 -m http.server`** and Save.

[image]

**Portal Response:**

- Browse the Web application URL `https://<app_name>.azurewebsites.net`:

[image]